# Struts2 performance impact on using tags & OGNL

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, el, jsp-tags

I'm trying to optimize JSP rendering time of a struts2 application. Initial analysis has shown that about 80-90% of the time is spent on rendering the JSPs. Action class logic amounts to around 20-10%. Methods calls made from the JSPs also don't amount to that much time. However some simple tag usages like `<s:set>, <s:if>` etc are taking 1-5ms some times (for evaluating 5-6 statements like that).

Referring to http://struts.apache.org/docs/make-struts-throw-exceptions-on-missing-properties-or-log-them.html,  I configured struts2 to throw exceptions on el failures. After configuring JSP execution fails with exceptions.
e.g. `<set var="prop1" value="actionMethod()"/>` fails with the above configuration. But if '`struts.el.throwExceptionOnFailure`' is set to '`false`' execution JSP doesn't fail.

I was wondering how much impact struts2 tags/ognl failures have on response times, and how to have the least performance impact when using tags/ognl (what techniques/best practices to follow) ?

Also why does some tag usages/ognl statements fails when '`struts.el.throwExceptionOnFailure`' is set to '`true`'?

struts2 version - 2.3.15
ognl version - 3.0.6

Comment: Which timings are you hitting ? 80-90% of what, 1 second, 2 seconds, 5 seconds ? Why EL if you can use OGNL, or at least JSTL ? Which version of Struts2 ? Old OGNL was slow, the latest versions are very fast but I guess JSTL is still faster... but it's a matter of milliseconds, BTW. If you measure an s:set in a 1-5 ms, how much of them do you have in a page to make it sensibly noticeable ?! Please expand your question. Also post a Firebug Net Panel view of the page being loaded, often static resources are not served (nor cached) properly.

Comment: @AndreaLigios we're only using struts2 tags and ognl. struts2 version is 2.3.15. Quick response times are very important in our app, current bottleneck seems to be JSP rendering time.

Comment: Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). It's impossible to understand all that you've said without code.

Comment: Ok then JSP EL (`${}`) is not involved here, if you are using only OGNL. Your version seems already a fast one, but you can still try a [newer version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ognl/ognl) and check if the timings change. Please consider upgrading Struts to at least 2.3.15.3, due to important security fix. Better to 2.3.16.3, or 2.3.20 if possible. If an SSCCE as requested by @RomanC is not an option, please post a JSP of yours as example (obscuring the code, if necessary), and provide informations about the timings I've asked you before. How much seconds ? 1,2,5 ?

Comment: And of course don't use OGNL if it's not the best practice in your opinion.

Comment: OGNL and some of the S2 tags are performance bottlenecks. Have you followed the performance tuning guide? In any case, most of the time I recommend doing as much data preparation work as possible in the data layer, keeping OGNL expressions to a minimum in the JSP layer (a good idea anyway).

Comment: @DaveNewton i've removed unwanted interceptors and set 'struts.freemarker.templatesCache' to 'true' (application is using ftl templates under 'divBased' theme)

Comment: @DevBlanked Without further info it'll be impossible to help other than to point you at the tuning tips: https://struts.apache.org/docs/performance-tuning.html